# Using xargs with input from a file

Tags: bash, scripting, xargs

Say I have a file with the following

```
bob
john
sue
```

Now these directly corrospond to (in this case) URL pattern such as `http://example.com/persons/bob.tar`, `john.tar`, `sue.tar`.

I would like to take these lines and run them through `xargs`. I don't know what is passed to the command being executed though. How do I access the parameter either from the prompt (say I want to simply echo each line like `cat file | xargs echo $PARAM`) or from a bash script.

Comment: I'm not quite following the question, sorry. In particular I'm not sure what "I don't know what is passed to the command being executed though" means

Comment: @Michael: When you run a list through `xargs` it breaks it up by line and feeds each line into a command, right? How do I access that if I need to say something like `cat file | xargs curl http://example.com/[PASSED FROM FILE].tar`?

Answer (score 93):

Michael's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3593/using-xargs-with-input-from-a-file/3598#3598) is right, and should sort out your problem. Running

```
cat file | xargs -I % curl http://example.com/persons/%.tar
```

will download files `bob.tar` `john.tar.` `sue.tar` as expected.

**BUT**: [cat here is useless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat)

rather use:

```
<file xargs -I % curl http://example.com/persons/%.tar
```

Comment: In my one file example it may not be ideal, however, `cat xaa xab xac xad ... xargs ...`

Comment: @Josh For some reason people tend to take unnecessary uses of cat really seriously here; I've been downvoted for it twice now

Comment: for the record, you got a +1 from me. I think using `cat` is fine really, just like to add more info... :)

Comment: Surely it should be `xargs -I % curl …` (*xargs* option before `curl` and its options/arguments). At the very least `xargs curl -I %` (where `-I %` is meant as an option to *xargs*, not *curl*) is not portable.

Comment: @Chris, nice catch, tnx. fixed.

Answer (score 19):

I think you're asking how to insert the individual lines pulled from `xargs`' stdin in the middle of a command, instead of just pasting it on the end always. If so, the `-I` flag takes a `replacement-string` argument; `xargs` will then replace `replacement-string` in the command with the line read from stdin:

```
$ cat file | xargs -I foobar curl http://example.com/foobar.tar
```

Comment: Okay, how about `curl http://example.com/foobar.tar > foobar.tar`?

Comment: @Josh K: `>` is a shell constructs, and won't work for `xargs`.  On the other hand, `curl -o` will write to a named file instead of stdout, like what `wget` does, so that's probably what you would like to use here.

Answer (score 16):

```
$ man xargs
...
       --arg-file=file
       -a file
              Read items from file instead of standard input.  If you use this
              option,  stdin  remains unchanged when commands are run.  Other-
              wise, stdin is redirected from /dev/null.
...
```

You may want to set `--delimiter=`/`-d` to `'\n'` as well.

---

On the other hand, if you are just trying to turn each line in the file into a URL,

```
$ sed -e 's#.*#http://example.com/persons/&.tar#' file
```

will do, and if you want to fetch all of them, just pipe that into `| wget -i`.

Answer (score 9):

another way with shell looping:

```
for i in `cat file`; do curl -I http://foo.com/$i; done
```

you can also run each iteration in the background by appending `&` prior to the last semicolon - for very large downloads this might be handy

Comment: You've [fallen for one of the classic blunders](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#arg-max)! <-- broken link, here's a cached version: [Useless Use of Cat Award](http://archive.is/fBdSf).

Comment: @Sorpigal That url is broken. What is the 'Classic Blunder'?

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs - useless use of cat, I've put a cached version of that link in the comment above.

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs: I specifically was linking to [Dangerous Backticks](http://archive.is/fBdSf#arg-max), but the use of cat is also needless if you change to a while construct: `while IFS= read i ; do curl ... ; done < file`

Answer (score 6):

With GNU Parallel you can do:

```
cat urls | parallel curl {} ">" {/}
```

Or:

```
cat persons | parallel curl http://example.com/persons/{}.tar ">" {}.tar
```

Watch the intro video for GNU Parallel to learn more:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ

Answer (score 2):

`while read VAR; do ... done` loop is simple yet very versatile:

```
while read word; do wget http://example.com/persons/$word; done < file
```

Answer (score 2):

Eventually, you can use as well:

```
xargs -n1 -a file -I % curl http://example.com/persons/%.tar
```

Comment: Does not using `-I` imply `-n 1`?  Also, the `-a` option is [non-standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html), so you would have to specify what implementation of `xargs` you're using.

Comment: Using `-I` imply `-x` and `-L` (max-lines), but not  `-n` ...  if I am not mistaken.     

In *xargs 4.7.0 GNU* `-a file ` is equal to  `--arg-file=file `

Answer (score 0):

This is a more general version of Stefan:s answer but I'm using awk in the middle to prepare the exact "string" that I would like xargs to execute. And then xargs is using bash to do the actual "work".

It is a little bit overkill for this example, but it is a general solution that with some modifications can solve many problems...

```
cat file | awk '{print "curl http://example.com/persons/"$1".tar"}' | xargs -0 bash -c
```